# why do I have to manually refresh review links?

Tags: support, review-queues, live-refresh

At this point I have to manually refresh the review pages, Is there an option to see when there are posts to be reviewed without having to refresh the page manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of these scripts

- [Review Stalker](https://stackapps.com/questions/4086/review-stalker-user-script) that does the refreshing for you. It refreshes every 15 seconds.
- [Review Queue Desktop Notification Script](https://stackapps.com/questions/6517/review-queue-desktop-notification-script) you are notified on the Desktop whenever new reviews are available,

These are found on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/), a site filled with all kind of tools, scripts, extensions, plugins to make life on the SE sites easier.